# C++ String Subcript Out of Range when using string.length() as end of for loop

Tags: c++

I have a C++ function that is supposed to iterate through the characters in a string and change it to lower case.  I am using the length of the input string as the end of the sequence, which works in example functions in the textbook, but gives me a "subscript out of range" error when trying to implement it in the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

string makeLower(const string& str);

int main() {
    string userString, lowerCaseUserString;

    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> userString;

    lowerCaseUserString = makeLower(userString);
    cout << lowerCaseUserString;

    return 0;
}

string makeLower(const string& str) {
    int i;
    string lowerCaseCopy;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 1)
        lowerCaseCopy[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    return lowerCaseCopy;
}
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You can use `std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });` to make a string lower case in place. You are indexing a default constructed string `lowerCaseCopy` in your function `makeLower`.

Comment: thank you all for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `lowerCaseCopy` string is empty, so indexing into it is undefined behavior.

You could use `push_back` to add elements:

```
string lowerCaseCopy;
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 1)
     lowerCaseCopy.push_back(tolower(str[i]));
```

Or you could allocate enough space for it before indexing:

```
string lowerCaseCopy(str.length());
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 1)
    lowerCaseCopy[i] = tolower(str[i]);
```

You could also simplify the first loop with a range-for:

```
string lowerCaseCopy;
for (auto c : str)
   lowerCaseCopy.push_back(tolower(c));
```